# How can a green leaved canna's flower color be found when not in bloom?

Tags: identification, flowering, canna

At a perennial sale once I found an unmarked canna with green leaves, and when I asked what color the flowers were, they said they didn't know. After looking at the leaves for a while, they decided it was probably yellow. Later that summer, I found they were right. How can I find that out for myself?

Comment: Undoubtedly a genetic test could be performed. Otherwise you could take a job selling canna. Experience is a good teacher.

Comment: Maybe the leaves of ones with red flowers have a reddish tinge?

Comment: Maybe they sold two different kinds and guessed?

Comment: They had many colors.

Comment: The genetic traits that make a yellow flower will have other super subtle effects on the plant. Perhaps, the ratio of stem thickness to leaf, or leaf colour tinge. There is no doubt humans have a largely untapped ability (in modern times anyway) to see these subtle differences, sometimes subconsciously. It's due to taking the information in subconsciously that it seems only 'probable' not definite that the flowers would be yellow. So I think @JoeHobbit is right. It's simply experience.

Comment: Theory #2: Luck (and great odds on yellow). If you look at the helpfully illustrated [Wikipedia page on Canna lily cultivars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Canna_cultivars), the majority (i.e. easily more than 50%) of the flowers could be described as "yellow".

Comment: Maybe they had divisions from two different people, and the two of them had a good look and decided yes, these leaves look like Sue's and hers are yellow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Orange colored cannas invariably have orange or yellow streaks on the leaves. Yellow cannas don't have orange streaked leaves. The almost white canna's streaks or similar variations in foliage will be very pale.